p4 after remapping client I need to unshelve my shelf
I had a client mapping (p4 client) and it was not good. I had to do it in the first place because the client had to include a path that the old client didn't have. I found the resulting layout not so good. I changed the mapping again (p4 client) and then did p4 sync ... but when I wanted to unshelve a shelf that I had unshelved in the old view, p4 said "can't unshelve". How do I get this shelf in the new layout of the client?

What's the rest of the error message?  It should say why you can't unshelve...

If the shelved file isn't in your new client view (which should result in an error message something like can't unshelve //depot/shelved/file, file not in client view), the only way to unshelve it is going to be to modify the view so that it includes the file.  If you include the full error message as well as p4 client -o that'll make it easy to help you.

I have two places where the same files have been accidently mapped. I somehow got //depot/a/b/c/d to be mapped to a place that corresponded to //depot/d SOMEHOW and now perforce seems to be acting as if it needs to maintain both. I should only have //depot/a/b/c/d and maybe have a "view" in the client file that shortcuts the path. I have error output that no one else has. Like "not in client" and other statements that don't make sense.

Like I said, if you update your question to include that information (the exact error messages you're getting, and your exact client view) I can probably help get you straightened out.  I'm not going to be able to diagnose exactly what's going on based on secondhand impressions that things aren't making sense (these are perfectly valid impressions to have, mind you, because I'm sure you've gotten twisted in some difficult-to-debug knot and the errors aren't as helpful as they could be, but I still need to see the actual errors to be able to reverse engineer the knot).
